# python wsgi logging to remote server is sent multiple times

Tags: python, logging, mod-wsgi, wsgi

In a apache/wsgi app I am trying to log what my app does to a remote rsyslog deamon. But I don't know why, the logs I was to record are recorded multiple times in my log file. The time I call the test url, I have one new log line,the second time I have two new lines (above the first one), and so on... I have no idea why and no clue. Would have know what might cause this behavior ?

Thanks

```
import logging, socket, os, json, requests, sys
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler

def application(environ, start_response):
        status = '200 OK'
        html_output = 'App test\n'
        logger = logging.getLogger('test app')
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler('/dev/log')
        formatter = logging.Formatter('Python: { "loggerName":"%(name)s", "timestamp":"%(asctime)s", "pathName":"%(pathname)s", "logRecordCreationTime":"%(created)f", "functionName":"%(funcName)s", "levelNo":"%(levelno)s", "lineNo":"%(lineno)d", "time":"%(msecs)d", "levelName":"%(levelname)s", "message":"%(message)s"}')
        handler.formatter = formatter
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.info('need to sync true')
        response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', str(len(html_output)))]
        start_response(status, response_headers)
        return [bytes(html_output,  'utf-8')]
```

Here are some log lines from /var/log/messages where you can see the same lines multiple times :

```
Mar 27 14:42:53 db-test Python[20249]: { "loggerName":"test app", "timestamp":"2020-03-27 13:42:53,687", "pathName":"/home/prebid-server/serverside-mediasquare/python/test.wsgi", "logRecordCreationTime":"1585316573.687927", "functionName":"application", "levelNo":"20", "lineNo":"18", "time":"687", "levelName":"INFO", "message":"need to sync true"}
Mar 27 14:42:53 db-test Python[20249]: { "loggerName":"test app", "timestamp":"2020-03-27 13:42:53,687", "pathName":"/home/prebid-server/serverside-mediasquare/python/test.wsgi", "logRecordCreationTime":"1585316573.687927", "functionName":"application", "levelNo":"20", "lineNo":"18", "time":"687", "levelName":"INFO", "message":"need to sync true"}
Mar 27 14:42:56 db-test Python[20249]: { "loggerName":"test app", "timestamp":"2020-03-27 13:42:56,194", "pathName":"/home/prebid-server/serverside-mediasquare/python/test.wsgi", "logRecordCreationTime":"1585316576.194655", "functionName":"application", "levelNo":"20", "lineNo":"18", "time":"194", "levelName":"INFO", "message":"need to sync true"}
Mar 27 14:42:56 db-test Python[20249]: { "loggerName":"test app", "timestamp":"2020-03-27 13:42:56,194", "pathName":"/home/prebid-server/serverside-mediasquare/python/test.wsgi", "logRecordCreationTime":"1585316576.194655", "functionName":"application", "levelNo":"20", "lineNo":"18", "time":"194", "levelName":"INFO", "message":"need to sync true"}
Mar 27 14:42:56 db-test Python[20249]: { "loggerName":"test app", "timestamp":"2020-03-27 13:42:56,194", "pathName":"/home/prebid-server/serverside-mediasquare/python/test.wsgi", "logRecordCreationTime":"1585316576.194655", "functionName":"application", "levelNo":"20", "lineNo":"18", "time":"194", "levelName":"INFO", "message":"need to sync true"}
Mar 27 14:42:57 db-test Python[20249]: { "loggerName":"test app", "timestamp":"2020-03-27 13:42:57,700", "pathName":"/home/prebid-server/serverside-mediasquare/python/test.wsgi", "logRecordCreationTime":"1585316577.700038", "functionName":"application", "levelNo":"20", "lineNo":"18", "time":"700", "levelName":"INFO", "message":"need to sync true"}
Mar 27 14:42:57 db-test Python[20249]: { "loggerName":"test app", "timestamp":"2020-03-27 13:42:57,700", "pathName":"/home/prebid-server/serverside-mediasquare/python/test.wsgi", "logRecordCreationTime":"1585316577.700038", "functionName":"application", "levelNo":"20", "lineNo":"18", "time":"700", "levelName":"INFO", "message":"need to sync true"}
Mar 27 14:42:57 db-test Python[20249]: { "loggerName":"test app", "timestamp":"2020-03-27 13:42:57,700", "pathName":"/home/prebid-server/serverside-mediasquare/python/test.wsgi", "logRecordCreationTime":"1585316577.700038", "functionName":"application", "levelNo":"20", "lineNo":"18", "time":"700", "levelName":"INFO", "message":"need to sync true"}
Mar 27 14:42:57 db-test Python[20249]: { "loggerName":"test app", "timestamp":"2020-03-27 13:42:57,700", "pathName":"/home/prebid-server/serverside-mediasquare/python/test.wsgi", "logRecordCreationTime":"1585316577.700038", "functionName":"application", "levelNo":"20", "lineNo":"18", "time":"700", "levelName":"INFO", "message":"need to sync true"}
```

Comment: Are you calling `application()` multiple times? Because each call would add another handler to the same logger, and thus duplicate the log.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. application() is called only once. And even if I called it twice of three times, it would not explain why for each page call the number of associated log lines grow exponentially.